# How to put a ember cli project under subversion control

Tags: git, svn, ember.js, ember-cli

We happen to use subversion and I want to put the new ember cli project under our version control with subversion.
What is the best way to do that?

Things I'm planning right now:

- I would have read the content from all the `.gitignore` files and put them on my svn ignore list as well.
- Check in everything else in the svn repository
- Add the output directory of the build to the ignore list as well

On checkout:

- Checkout the directory
- Run the proposed commands from http://www.ember-cli.com/#cloning-an-existing-project

  `cd my-app && npm install && bower install`

Am I missing anything? Put anything else on the ignore list for svn? What about all the git files?

Comment: The output should already be in `.gitignore` (`/dist`). Other than that, it looks okay to me. You can remove `.git`, `.gitignore`. `.gitkeep` you might keep, because its sole purpose is to have the directory not be empty so git can commit it. SVN can commit empty directories, but apparently [not without hassle](http://serverfault.com/questions/48481/add-directory-structure-to-svn-without-files), so you may delete or keeep `.gitkeep` as you prefer.

Comment: In the directory `dist` I can only find `dist/.gitkeep` and `dist/assets/.gitkeep`, no `.gitignore`

Comment: I meant: remove the root .gitignore and .git; keep .gitkeep if you want; and as for your question whether to add the output directory of build to ignore, if you ignored everything from .gitignore, you did it already.

Comment: thanks! svn seems to be not "state of the art" anymore... feels funny to build an app witch such a state of the art framework but put it under version control with a dinsosaur ;) - you could possibly make that an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeated from comments:

> - I would have read the content from all the .gitignore files and put them on my svn ignore list as well.

Okay

> - Check in everything else in the svn repository

Okay

> - Add the output directory of the build to the ignore list as well

Already done if you did step 1 (build directory is `/dist` that you find in `.gitignore`)

> What about all the git files?

Delete `.git` and `.gitignore` from the root directory. Remove `.gitkeep` if you can deal with the hassle of adding empty directories, or keep them to auto-check-in the directories where they act as placeholders. If the name bugs you, rename them to `.svnkeep`, `.dummy` or `.potatohead`, they will not do anything differently (neither in svn nor in git) :)